# Trying to make a python fighting game state machine. How can I capture keyboard input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python, I mostly use c# in the context of Unity, but I'm trying to learn.
I wanted to try and make a basic state machine for a fighting game, where a stun timer increases by specific amounts depending on which button the user presses (IE Heavy attack adds 3, Medium attack adds 2, light attack adds 1) and decays over time.

At the moment, I want to bind the aforementioned attacks to keys, suck as hitting the q key on the keyboard and triggering a heavy attack.

That's where I'm stuck. I'm just trying to get hitting the "q" key to print a message in the console, but I'm lost on what the simplest way to do that would be.

An equivalent in unity/c# would be the following:
if the key is pressed, print the log message in the console.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("q"))
        {
            Debug.Log("q key was pressed");
        }
```

How can I do this in the simplest way possible in python?

My python version is Python 3.10.13 and I am on Mac OS Sonoma 14.1 if this helps.

Thanks!

So far, I've tried pynput, but I'm a bit confused on the keyboard listener functionality, and I'm just wondering if that's the best way to do this.

Comment: If you plan to make games in Python, then you can take a look at the Pygame library. It provides a base for making nice games. However, if you're new to Python, then I'd recommend learning Turtle first. It will help you learn the basics of graphics in Python

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to achieve this, but you can use simple user input

```
if input() == "q":
    print("q key was pressed")
```

For details you can go here(https://cs.stanford.edu/people/nick/py/python-input.html) or here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: I don’t think that this is what the OP wants

Answer (score 0):

The python package turtle (always included in python) has a listen function. You can build games like snake or turtle street crossing etc... Maybe this is a good way to start the python journey. Here is a basic example:

```
from turtle import Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)
def on_left():
    print("leftclick")

def on_right():
    print("rightclick")

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(key="Left", fun=on_left)
screen.onkey(key="Right", fun=on_right)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to make games with Turtle in Python, then the following code will help:

```
import turtle
 
#Just a function
def find():
    #do something

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.onkey(func,"Up") #Execute function on pressing the up arrow key
```

Another library is Pygame. To get input in Pygame, you can use the following code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

#other code

while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #Execute code if left arrow key is pressed
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        #do something
```

Turtle is better if you are new to Python. It’ll help to learn the basics of graphics in Python. If you’re quite experienced, you can have a go at Pygame. With the right skills, you can even make commercial games using Pygame.

Comment: Thank you, I'm testing out turtle at the moment, but the following code isn't running and im not sure why:
`import turtle
from turtle import *

#Screen stuff
screen = turtle.Screen()

def testFunc():
    # if key 'up arrow' is pressed 
    print('You pressed up arrow!') 
    screen.bgcolor("green") 

screen.mainloop() #This keeps the window alive while we do stuff
screen.onkey(testFunc,"Up") #Execute function on pressing the up arrow key
screen.listen() #listen for key input`

Comment: @Mitch If you face a problem, it is wise to ask a new question